# When I attempt to change the root password by following the documentation, I get a SQL Syntax Error or the password doesn't update

Tags: sql, linux, mariadb, change-password

I'm running MariaDB MySQL on a Linux machine. When I attempt to change the password following the documentation, MySQL gives me the following error upon starting:

```
2017-11-17  9:25:47 139640910462912 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
ERROR: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
   to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 
   'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pA$sWord^';' at line 1
2017-11-17  9:25:47 139640910462912 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.28-MariaDB'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

[The specific documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html) I'm following:

> The instructions assume that you will start the MySQL server from the
>   Unix login account that you normally use for running it. For example,
>   if you run the server using the `mysql` login account, you should log in
>   as `mysql` before using the instructions. Alternatively, you can log in
>   as `root`, but in this case you must start `mysqld` with the `--user=mysql`
>   option. If you start the server as `root` without using `--user=mysql`,
>   the server may create root-owned files in the data directory, such as
>   log files, and these may cause permission-related problems for future
>   server startups. If that happens, you will need to either change the
>   ownership of the files to mysql or remove them.
>
> Log on to your system as the Unix user that the MySQL server runs as
>   (for example, `mysql`).
>
> Stop the MySQL server if it is running. Locate the `.pid` file that
>   contains the server's process ID. The exact location and name of this
>   file depend on your distribution, host name, and configuration. Common
>   locations are `/var/lib/mysql/`, `/var/run/mysqld/`, and
>   `/usr/local/mysql/data/`. Generally, the file name has an extension of
>   `.pid` and begins with either `mysqld` or your system's host name.
>
> Stop the MySQL server by sending a normal `kill` (not `kill -9`) to the
>   `mysqld` process. Use the actual path name of the .pid file in the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> shell> kill `cat /mysql-data-directory/host_name.pid`
> ```
>
> Use backticks (not forward quotation marks) with the cat command. These cause the
>   output of cat to be substituted into the kill command.

NOTE: I used `top` to end the process. I'm certain it is not running.

```
$ ps aux | grep mysql
user 30201  0.0  0.0  10884  2296 pts/6    S+   09:43   0:00 grep mysql
```

> Create a text file containing the password-assignment statement on a
>   single line. Replace the password with the password that you want to
>   use.
>
> MySQL 5.7.6 and later:
>
> `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';`
>
> MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:
>
> `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');`
>
> Save the
>   file. This example assumes that you name the file `/home/me/mysql-init`.
>   The file contains the password, so do not save it where it can be read
>   by other users. If you are not logged in as `mysql` (the user the server
>   runs as), make sure that the file has permissions that permit `mysql` to
>   read it.
>
> Start the MySQL server with the special --init-file option:
>
> ```
> shell> mysqld --init-file=/home/me/mysql-init &
> ```
>
> The server executes
>   the contents of the file named by the `--init-file` option at startup,
>   changing the `'root'@'localhost'` account password.
>
> Other options may be necessary as well, depending on how you normally
>   start your server. For example, `--defaults-file` may be needed before
>   `--init-file`.
>
> After the server has started successfully, delete `/home/me/mysql-init`.

MariaDB Version:

```
$ sudo pacman -Q | grep mariadb
libmariadbclient 10.1.28-1
mariadb 10.1.28-1
mariadb-clients 10.1.28-1
```

File `/change_root_password.txt`:

```
$ ls -lha /change_root_pwd.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 56 Nov 17 09:24 /change_root_pwd.txt
$ cat /change_root_pwd.txt 
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pA$sWord^';
```

Command used to start `mysqld` that results in the above mentioned error:

```
sudo mysqld --user=mysql --init-file=/change_root_pwd.txt
```

[I found this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html) with an alternate SQL query:

> If the ALTER USER statement fails to reset the password, try repeating
>   the procedure using the following statements to modify the user table
>   directly:
>
> ```
> UPDATE mysql.user
>     SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
>     WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
> ```

When I try that instead of the `ALTER USER` query, I get no error, but the password does not get updated.

Comment: You are using MariaDB, why are you consulting the MySQL documentation? Although they have the same origin, they might deviate (although quick glance at the MariaDB documentation suggests they don't in this regard).

Comment: That's a valid point, but as you said, there's no deviation in this specific instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I should have understood the difference between MariaDB and MySQL before asking this question.

I do not know why using that method to reset the root Password does not work, but MariaDB has a simpler way to change the root Password which is documented here:

https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mariadb/how-to-install-mariadb-on-centos-7

> ### Reset the MariaDB Root Password
>
> If you forget your root MariaDB password, it can be reset.
>
> Stop the current MariaDB server instance, then restart it with an option to not ask for a password:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl stop mariadb
> sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
> ```
>
> Reconnect to the MariaDB server with the MariaDB root account:
>
> ```
> mysql -u root
> ```
>
> Use the following commands to reset root’s password. Replace password with a strong password:
>
> ```
> use mysql;
> update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("password") WHERE USER='root';
> flush privileges;
> exit
> ```
>
> Then restart MariaDB:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl start mariadb
> ```

Comment: it not work 
i have try alter
`update user SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD("password") WHERE USER='root';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0'`
and alter

`ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1
`
and both dont work on me, 
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2